# Accept a pop up dialog in ios using appium without having the appium driver instance

Tags: java, ios, selenium, appium

I use java to run an appium test, and there is an issue with a pop up notification dialog that appears before I have the instance of the appium driver.
Because of that I am not able to press the accept button.
I read here that I should use: 
capabilities.setCapability("autoAcceptAlerts",true)

this also not working.

Any idea how can I solve this issue?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue resolved after adding Thread.sleep(10000) right after I get the instance of the Appium driver.